# how to handle boolean value with AFNetworking parsing JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have some JSON that comes back like this:

```
"items":[
{
"has_instore_image": false
}
]
```

If I output the value like this:

```
NSLog(@"has_instore_image val: %@", [item objectForKey:@"has_instore_image"]);
```

I get

```
has_instore_image val: 0
```

but if I test like this:

```
if([item objectForKey:@"has_instore_image"]==0){
  NSLog(@"no, there is not an instore image");
}else{
...
```

It always goes to the else statement... hmmm.. How would you suggest I get the BOOL value and test? I've read through the BOOL questions here and am just confused this is not working as I'd anticipate.

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSDictionary`'s instance method `objectForKey` returns an `id`, not a primitive value.

If it's a `boolean`, `int`, `float`, etc number-like value in JSON, it will serialized to an `NSNumber` by Apple's `NSJSONSerialization` class and most/all other common JSON parsers in iOS.

If you want to get the `BOOL` value out of it, you can do something like this:

```
BOOL has_instore_image = [[item objectForKey:@"has_instore_image"] boolValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a pointer with an integer here

```
 [item objectForKey:@"has_instore_image"]==0
```

You should use

```
 [item objectForKey:@"has_instore_image"].integerValue==0
```

Also note that a `BOOL` of `NO` equals 0.

The `NSLog`statement in your code prints a 0, but only because if you give `NSLog`an object as parameter, the objects `description`is called.

Answer (score 1):

i will suggest to hold these id type (returned from dictionary) to NSNumber .

```
 NSNumber *boolNum=(NSNumber*)[item objectForKey:@"has_instore_image"];
```

after that you can get bool value from boolNum

```
[boolNum boolValue]
```

try this

```
if([boolNum boolValue]==NO){
    NSLog(@"no, there is not an instore image");
 }else
{

 }
```